# Magento 1.91 CE - Customers Cant login

Tags: magento, authentication, magento-1.9

Hi all our website is Caged.eu and we have customised a Template from pre 1.9. Magento allows customer to register but when they try to sign in using that login details login page doesnt respond, this also happens when they ask to resend password it send reset details but still doesnt work.

Oddly the click facebook link to sign up login does work which is another extension we are ready to release but after getting it this well done would hate to have to change template.

Im sure its something stupid but would really appreciate your help guys

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9 the forms are unable to store the data as formkey missing. Try to add the key then you can be able to sign in. Add `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` this at line no 41 below `<form>` tag in app/design/frontend/[your theme package]/[your theme]/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
And check whether you can update product quantity in cart, there also formkey is missing.

Comment: Hi thankyou so much for reply tried this but still doesnt do anything:

Comment: My template is t-shirt and looking at the directory structure I have:

Comment: May I know the what is the error message ot shows?
It is not showing the error message but simply redirecting to the login page right?

Comment: Just does exactly that looks like you havent done anything just blank standard login page

Answer (score 0):

After you had added the line `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>`

Perhaps you need to to flush magneto cache from magento admin (System->Cache management), then you can try the frontend customer login again.

Answer (score 0):

Copy `base/default/template/customer` and `base/default/template/persistent` to your `theme/template`

Answer (score 0):

As already replied in [magento.stackexchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/customer-login-doesnt-work-in-1-9/40913#40913?s=e068d38bb3d44630abb6319841c559e5) you should edit

```
/app/design/frontend/default/template-name/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
```

and inside the "login form" form, after the

```
<ul class="form-list">
```

you should insert

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

and this will solve your problem, as it did with mine.
Hope this helps

**so be it - manemoi**

Theodore